# How to access embedded files in SWFKit

Tags: flash, flv, embedded-resource, exe

I'm using SWFKit to create a native windows app from flash project. I want to embed video in project via SWFKit and then use it in flash.

Looks like I've found a way to embed external file but I can't find manual about how to access this embedded file via ActionScript in flash movie.

[image]

So the question is how can I access file "bridge.flv" in compiled project using ActionScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem is solved.**

It appears to be pretty easy actually. Once file is embedded it can be accessed by relative path as if it was present in current application directory.

For example embedded bridge.flv can be accessed by Flex VideoDisplay component in this way:

```
video.source = "bridge.flv";
```